# How to add SipHash patch from kernel v4.11 to v4.4.52

Tags: kernel, git, yocto

How to add SipHash patch from kernel v4.11 to v4.4.52 to replace the md5 cryptographic function with the Siphash for adding more security in v4.4.52? Can we do this? what is the proper way to do? I was trying to add the patch from below link: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=2c956a60778cbb6a27e0c7a8a52a91378c90e1d1

but getting error. Can someone help?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using Yocto SDK (krogoth 2.1.2) to add the patch and trying to add the patch in recipe-kernel.  Yocto running in the ubuntu 23.04. Is this helpful? Please let me know if u need anything else. thanks.